# How many times can you refresh an oAuth2 Token?

Tags: google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

I want to use Google Calendar API to synchronize Google Calender with our Application. We have a lot of users and the idea is, that they log in once and I just keep refreshing the security token so I can continue the synchronization. Is there a limit how many times or how long after authorization you can refresh a token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an OAuth 2.0 spec perspective - there's no limit.  I haven't heard of one for Google.  Typically refresh tokens are revoked by the user themselves (i.e.: cutting the authorized application link).